# How to limit the number of mappers in Hive job?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapr

In my three node cluster, i have optimized all the required parameters for the performance. But this is not much helping in my case,
All our hive tables are created with parquet format, when my team tries to load from external table to internal table,
please find the script below,

```
ksh -c 'hadoop fs -rm -R 
 hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/bistore_sit_cycle2.db/wt_consumer/d_partition_number=0;
        hive -e  "set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
        insert into bistore_sit_cycle2.wt_consumer
        partition(d_partition_number)
        select * from bistore_sit_cycle2.ext_wt_consumer;
        set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=strict;"'
```

it takes more than 2 hours to load, the hive job created with 718 mappers and running with 2 containers on each node, concurrently  5 mappers only running for this job. 
the load was 85M records and 35GB approximately.

How to run like this jobs with less mappers and how to increase the concurrency of running mappers !!!???

```
And this is my complete Cluster and YARN configuration details,

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v3 @ 3.20GHz (16 physical cores)(32 hyper threaded) 
RAM:256GB 
DISK:1.2TB x 16
MapR 5.0.0 - Community Edition
        mapreduce.map.memory.mb=10g
        mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=16g
        yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=16g
        yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts=15g
        yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores=16
        mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores=12
        mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores=16
        mapreduce.map.disk=1.5
        mapreduce.reduce.disk=3.99
        mapreduce.map.java.opts=9g
        mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=15g
        mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=1024
        mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor=1024
        mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies=48
        yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=180g
        yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=180g
        yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=4g
        yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=32
        yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio=3.2
        HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=32g
```

Comment: _"All our hive tables are created with parquet format"_ >> even the EXTERNAL files???

Comment: If your inputs are CSV files, you can tell Hive to process multiple small files per Mapper -- see my comment below

Comment: You can also try to reduce the container size -- the default might be way too high for that specific case, even with `CombineInputFormat`.

Comment: To check the default container size, `set mapreduce.map.memory.mb ; set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb ; set yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb ;` cf. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml >> also `set hive.tez.container.size ;` if you are using TEZ cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Tez

Comment: Duh... `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts` does not look like anything you would pass on a Java command-line; and I wonder why a YARN AppMaster would require 16 GB and 16 (virtual) cores for doing, well, nothing except launching & monitoring the Map & Reduce containers. Is that what you call "optimization"?!?

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers spawned for a hive query depends on the input split. You have 35 GB of data and you are getting 718 mappers. That means you have a split size around 49 MB (35*1024/718). Your cluster has only three nodes and based on your YARN  container size settings it might only be able to spawn 5 containers atmost. In order to increase parallelism you have add more containers, that is vertically or horizontally scale your cluster nodes.   More number or mappers is what you need to increase performance, less number of mappers means less parallelism.

Comment: Objection: Hadoop `CombineFileInputFormat` has been specifically created to buffer multiple small splits per Mapper; used in Hive via `hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat` property: _"Whether to combine small input files **so that fewer mappers are spawned**"_ -- see also `hive.input.format` in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties >> caveat: this works wth TextFile or SequenceFile only.

Comment: I agree. But I don't think karthee uses CombineInputFormat. He is  getting 5 containers out of three nodes is optimum assuming nodes are low end  commodity hardware. If it is server grade hardware he can play around yarn container settings to yield maximum number of containers.

Comment: Hi Despicable me & Samson Scharfrichter...please find my new edited question, i have added my complete configuration details. Thanks

Comment: i have tried with these properties too...<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.maps</name>
<value>6</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.maps</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
<value>10</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
<value>6</value>
</property>

Comment: My suggestion is that you try to figure out why you are getting only 5 containers at most, like you can check for queue allocation and yarn container minimum size settings. I don't think you should reduce number of mappers since you got 35 gb parquet data.

Comment: Hi Despicable me..my yarn container config's are,yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 4g,yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 180g, i don't know what else to change in the config's ?? and in any given job only 2 containers are running for a each node! So totally 6 containers running!

Comment: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.3/bk_installing_manually_book/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html

Comment: Check out above link and determine how many containers your cluster can have. Tweak memory settings to spawn more number of containers..